# Cannot publish because a project failed to build and Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\MyApplication.exe' Errors

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, deployment, clickonce

I am striving to get the source of my issue but no luck. I did check almost all suggestions to fix this problem when publishing project (publishing using right-click, checked DevExpress is not installed).

-Regarding DevExpress the application have some of it's assemblies.

**- Cannot publish because a project failed 

- Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\MyApplication.exe'**

I did send publishing diagnostic to the Output and get this :

```
Task "GenerateApplicationManifest" (TaskId:158)
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2580,9): error MSB3113: Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\MyApplication.exe'.
Done executing task "GenerateApplicationManifest" -- FAILED. (TaskId:158)
Done building target "GenerateApplicationManifest" in project "MyApplication.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:194)
```

Can someone list all things I have to check to get this issue fixed ?

Comment: Confusing.  Reads to me like right click DevExpress but DevExpress is not installed?

Comment: Sorry,I was quite tired and in a hurry. If anything unclear, please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the problem today. In my particular case, it was caused by this [Microsoft Windows Update](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/2661254).

I uninstalled that update and publish began working as it always had. This is only a temporary work around and means you should probably regenerate your keys/certificates.

Comment: Thanks @SpectralGhost, this case gonna be added to the issue's checklist. My problem has been resolved since I moved to VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on you **Project**
2. Click **Publish**
3. Go to **Settings** Tab
4. Click **File Publish Options**
5. Check All the options in the tab (As seen in attached image)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and explain a bit, why you suggest this recipe. For more guidance see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer